# TCP four-way handshake

Tags: tcp, handshake

Four-way handshake connection termination can be reduced to three-way and even two way one. Is it possible the three-way handshake connection establishment would be extended to four-way?

```
SYN=>
<=ACK
<=SYN
ACK=>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the semantics of SYN and ACK it should be possible to send SYN+ACK in different packets and those delay the handshake. E.g. client sends a SYN, server replies with an ACK to acknowledge the wish of the client for a new connection, but it does not grant the wish yet. Later the server sends a SYN and gets the matching ACK back from the client and the connection is established. But I doubt that anybody does connection establishment this way and it might be, that some OS will croak on it.

But, there is another scenario for a four-way-handshake, however with a different ordering of the packets. It could happen, if both side try to establish a connection to the other side at the same time, e.g. both send a SYN to the peer, and get an ACK back. It is described in the RFC 793 (TCP) section 3.4. But I doubt you will ever see such a handshake, because it does not fit into the typical client-server-scenario where one end is waiting for connects and the other end does the connect.

Edit: the handshake you envision exists and it is called "split handshake". See http://hackmageddon.com/2011/04/17/tcp-split-handshake-attack-explained/ . And like I expected, it is not universally supported.

Comment: "Given the semantics ... it should be possible" I'm not sure if you prove the point basing on your RFC knowledges or just supposed it.

Comment: The semantic of ACK is only to acknowledge that data are received, the semantic of SYN is only to request a connection. Both flags are orthogonal to each other and don't have a special meaning when used together, similar to FIN and ACK, so it should not matter if they are send together or in separate packets.